# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context using IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting `Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context` while using all IEnumerable objects... I have no idea what is wrong here.
Here's my models:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

}
public class UserRoleEditViewModel
{

    [DisplayName("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Roles")]
    public IEnumerable<UserRoleViewModel> UserRoles { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        UserRoleEditViewModel model = new UserRoleEditViewModel
        {                
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Id = user.Id,
            UserRoles = db.UserRoles.Select(x=> new UserRoleViewModel(){Name = x.RoleName, IsChecked = x.Users.Contains(user)}).AsEnumerable()                
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the View:

```
            @foreach (var userRoleViewModel in Model.UserRoles)//<ERR
            {
                <div>
                    @Html.Hidden(userRoleViewModel.Name)
                    @Html.CheckBox(userRoleViewModel.IsChecked.ToString())
                    @Html.Label(userRoleViewModel.Name, userRoleViewModel.Name)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

tried this too:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.UserRoles.Count(); i++) //<ERR
            {                    
                <div>
                    @Html.Hidden(Model.UserRoles.ToList()[i].Name)
                    @Html.CheckBox(Model.UserRoles.ToList()[i].IsChecked.ToString())
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserRoles.ToList()[i].IsChecked, Model.UserRoles.ToList()[i].Name)
                </div>
            }
```

My viewmodels are all IEnumerable'd... so, I have no idea what is wrong here.

Lines above marked "//

nor

@foreach (var userRoleViewModel in Model.UserRoles)

Comment: and I've tried tacking on .AsEnumerable() everywhere to no avail...

Comment: the lines marked "//<ERR" above.

Comment: Not related (Matt Burland's answer explains why you get the error) but you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection (it will not bind) and you cannot use a `for` loop on `IEnumerable<T>` - change the property to `IList<T>` to use a `for` loop or use an `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your error is probably here:

```
UserRoles = db.UserRoles.Select(x=> 
    new UserRoleViewModel(){Name = x.RoleName, IsChecked = x.Users.Contains(user)})
    .AsEnumerable()
```

The problem is that you can't translate that in SQL. There's no SQL statement that will construct your `UserRoleViewModel` object. So what you'll need to do is to select the data you need from the database first, and then use that to construct your object. For example, something like this:

```
// You can create anonymous types in LINQ to SQL, so do that first
UserRoles = db.UserRoles.Select(x => new { x.RoleName, IsChecked = x.Users.Contains(user) })
    .ToList()    // this forces the database to actually return data
    // Now we can actually construct your object because we aren't doing on the database
    .Select(x => new UserRoleViewModel() { Name = x.RoleName, IsChecked = x.IsChecked });
```

Comment: no its where I marked the error lines with  "//<ERR"

Comment: @Beau: It actually is there. The error doesn't pop up until your force the execution of the statement when you do `Count()` or try to enumerate with `foreach`, but it's origin is where you set up the select.

Comment: In that line, I am trying to set IsChecked (bool) based on if the UserRole is assigned to this user ( used eariler: User user = db.Users.Find(id);) It's an older Code-first app, fyi. I have three tables, Users, UserRoles, and UsersInRoles which is just a linking table with RoleID<>UserId columns.

Comment: @Beau: That's not really relevant. Your problem is that you can translate constructing a `UserRoleViewModel` into a SQL statement. Hence the error message *Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context*

Comment: I get it, I was just elaborating so you knew there were outside navigation props, etc. I tried your re-container code above to no avail. Same error.

Comment: @Beau, You could try just materializing the query first - `UserRoles = db.UserRoles.ToList().Select(...`

Comment: I have, and I think you're right. There's no reverse navigation allowed to the nav prop of 'Users'... I'll figure it out, but you we're right. I marked as answer. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I wound up doing this ugliness instead:

```
  List<UserRoleViewModel> vmList = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();
        foreach (var userRole in db.UserRoles)
        {
            UserRoleViewModel urVM = new UserRoleViewModel()
            {
                Name = userRole.RoleName
            };

            if (user.UserRoles.Contains(userRole))
                urVM.IsChecked = true;
            else
                urVM.IsChecked = false;

            vmList.Add(urVM);
        }

        model.UserRoles = vmList;
```